# Are standard iterator operations allowed to throw?

Tags: c++

Consider a standard iterator where it is necessary to allocate memory for traversing a data structure. Does the standard allow an iterator to throw an exception if memory cannot be allocated? As an example, think of an input iterator for tree data structures. In this case, to traverse the tree you have to either add and maintain a pointer to the parent of each node (which would slow down operations not needing such a pointer, as for insert/erase/find on the tree) or use a stack to help the iterator store the pointers to the traversed nodes. In this case, while advancing the stack could grow until there is no more free memory and the iterator is compelled to throw.

Comment: "In this case, to traverse the tree you have to either add and maintain a pointer to the parent of each node " Each node *should* have a pointer to its parent. Otherwise it's a "forward" tree, where you can only go down. I would say that an iterator that used a stack would be broken for both relying on a global or shared object (thus making it non-thread-safe) and for allocating memory just for traversing the tree. Note that the iterators for `std::forward_list` in C++11 are forward iterators; you *can't* go back at all.

Comment: @Nicol Who said the stack would be global or shared? The stack is associated to the iterator instance. Furthermore, stacks are probably the only way to implement *input iterators* on  trees where nodes have pointers to their successors only.

Comment: Input iterators do not *insert* elements into the data structure. They can only read and modify elements that already exist. Output iterators can, but you'll notice that most of those are iterator adapters for *containers*, not iterators. And tree nodes should point to their parents.

Comment: @Nicol. I have never talked about inserters. I have talked about *input iterators*.With regard to these iterators, the only method involved in my question is operator++() used for advancing. To advance in a tree where nodes do not have pointers to their parents, you'll have to use an stack. I don't see other ways. I also said that using a parent pointer in each node would slow down methods like insert/remove/find on the *tree*, since such a pointer is not necessary for these methods to be implemented efficiently,although they might help with the implementation of a safe input iterator.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes an iterator method in C++ is allowed to throw and as you pointed out can throw in certain circumstances.

The only class of functions in C++ that can't throw is a destructor.  And really that's just by convention (because it makes certain operations nearly impossible to do correctly).  Destructors can throw, it's just very bad to let them do so.

Individual functions can be marked with `throw()` to prevent them from throwing.

Comment: "The only function in C++ that can't throw is a destructor." Not true. The standard defines quite a few standard library functions that are not allowed to throw. For example, most of the constructors of `auto_ptr` are designated `throw()` in C++03, which means that they can't throw. In C++11, just about every `swap` implementation is defined with `noexcept`.

Comment: @NicolBolas I was more trying to make a general statement about whether or not a class / type of function was allowed to throw.  The `throw()` modifier certainly says an individual function can't throw.  I'll add a note about it though.  I'm not familiar with `noexcept`, do you have a good reference page for that.

Comment: @JaredPar: It's new syntax introduced in C++11.  Which Visual C++ has so far ignored, although it should be one of the easiest things to implement (almost identical to `throw()` + a type trait).  See section 15.4 and 5.3.7 of the C++11 Standard.